# jQuery When, abort multiple Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

How can a jQuery [when](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.when) deferred object which has multiple Ajax calls be **stopped** (aborted), so any pending Ajax calls will not be called?

Example code (minimal):

```
var deferred = $.when(
  $.getJSON( "a.json" ),
  $.getJSON( "b.json" )
)
.done(( res )=>{
  // whatever...
});
// abort the all AJAX calls after N miliseconds
setTimeout(()=>{ deferred.abort() }, 2000);
```

But of course, one cannot simply do `deferred.abort()` since the `abort` method does not exist.

Comment: do the values returned by $.getJSON have an abort?

Comment: `$.getJSON` by itself does have an `abort` method, but I want a robust solution and not to manually attach each `$.getJSON` to a variable and then abort them one by one..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a feature of the promise you get back from `$.when`. You can readily write it yourself, though: *(See below for an alternative, though.)*

```
function whenWithAbort(...xhrs) {
    return {
        abort() {
            xhrs.forEach(xhr => {
               xhr.abort();
            });
        },
        promise: $.when(...xhrs)
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var ops = whenWithAbort(
  $.getJSON( "a.json" ),
  $.getJSON( "b.json" )
)
.promise.done(( res )=>{
  // whatever...
});
// abort the all AJAX calls after N miliseconds
setTimeout(()=>{ ops.abort() }, 2000);
```

---

Or actually, more generically, just a `when`-with-array:

```
function whenPlus(...list) {
    return {
        list,
        promise: $.when(...list)
    };
}
```

Then:

```
var ops = whenWithAbort(
  $.getJSON( "a.json" ),
  $.getJSON( "b.json" )
)
.promise.done(( res )=>{
  // whatever...
});
// abort the all AJAX calls after N miliseconds
setTimeout(()=>{ ops.list.forEach(op => { op.abort() } }, 2000);
```

Or you could give it a method that calls a named method on all entries:

```
function whenPlus(...list) {
    return {
        list,
        callOnEach(method) {
            list.forEach(entry => { entry[method]() });
        },
        promise: $.when(...list)
    };
}
```

Then:

```
var ops = whenWithAbort(
  $.getJSON( "a.json" ),
  $.getJSON( "b.json" )
)
.promise.done(( res )=>{
  // whatever...
});
// abort the all AJAX calls after N miliseconds
setTimeout(()=>{ ops.callOnEach("abort") }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fine answer. I chose a slightly different way, but marked your answer (as accepted) as it was more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing:

```
var ajaxCalls = [
    $.getJSON( "a.json" ),
    $.getJSON( "b.json" )
];

$.when(...ajaxCalls)
    .done(( res )=>{
      // whatever...
    });

// abort the all AJAX calls after N miliseconds
setTimeout(()=>{ ajaxCalls.forEach(a => a.abort()) }, 2000);
```

---

Too bad the `when` method result doesn't also exposes the list of arguments supplied to it, so it could be accessed directly (and aborted in this case).