# jQuery 3.1.0 then(), done() and when() error swallowing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery 3.1.0, I am creating an unknown number of `$.ajax()` requests and adding the resulting promise(s) into an array using:

```
myArray.push($.ajax(...).promise());
```

Once all of the requests are completed I want to call a function, which I understand can be done using:

```
$.when.apply($, myArray).then(myFunction, errorHandlingFunction);
```

However, myFunction is throwing an error that is being swallowed by jQuery (during testing all my function did was call throw new `Error()`). I can see that execution enters the catch after calling `mightThrow()` and correctly reject's the deferred but this is never shown in the console.

Even doing the following, which omits the apply call, results in the error being swallowed completely; the debugger line is also never hit:

```
myArray[0].then(function() {
    throw new Error('test error');
}, function() { debugger; });
```

Removing the `when()` and performing the following causes execution to break on the throw:

```
myArray[0].done(() => {
    throw new Error('test error');
}).fail(function(){ debugger; });
```

It seems that errors that occur in the function executed by `then()` are always swallowed. In addition, `$.when(...).done(...)` also results in the error being swallowed if the function inside `done()` throws.

Have I misunderstood something or is this a bug/feature of jQuery?

Comment: see my answer as it relates to your code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39206980/104380

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use `.then(myFunction).fail(myErrorHandling)`. Throwing the error within `myFunction` will reject the new promise created by `then()` which then can be handled in `fail()`.

The error handling function in `.then(myFunction, myErrorHandling)` is called when the promise received by `then()` is rejected. This is only the case when at least one of your ajax requests from the `$.when()` fails.

Comment: This must have been the only combination I didn't try! Thank you, marked as answer.

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

For Promises you should use `.catch(function(error){})` or the JQuery `.fail(function(error){})`, `.then` is only called on success, so if it throws an error you can't see it.

Javascript:

```
myArray[0].then(function() {
    console.log('I am a success');
}).catch(function(error){
    console.error('I am an error', error);
});
```

JQuery:

```
myArray[0].done(function() {
        console.log('I am a success');
    }).fail(function(error){
        console.error('I am an error', error);
    });
```

Cheers

Comment: The problem would manifest when, in your second example, the console.log() call threw an error. This would happen silently.

Comment: That's not true, just tried both examples and the error is throwed:

Javascript:

`new Promise(function(resolve){
resolve();
}).then(function() {
    throw new Error('test error');
}, function() { debugger; });`

JQuery:

`$.ajax({method: 'get',url: 'http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/'}).promise().done(function(){throw new Error('test error');});`.

If the error is not throwed to you, it means that there is something else wrong.

Comment: In your last example, change the `.done()` to `then()` or try wrapping the promise in a `$.when()`. That was causing my problem that was answered.

Comment: Tried both cases, and it keeps throwing the error correctly, happy you find the answer you were looking for.